# Why my button never stops?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, switch-statement

In my code, I am using a `switch` statement. When the variable (`returnString`) (and no, it is just named as String, it is actually an integer) is 0,1,2 or 3, I just set the `TextView` to something and in case it is 4, it goes to my other activity using an `intent`. In the other hand, if `EditText`s are null, it ignores them and start the other activity. I want it to stop and set the `TextView` to `"Please enter username or password"`.

```
switch (returnString) {
            case 0: tv.setText("Invalid Entry. Please re-enter Username or Password - 0.");

                break;

            case 1: tv.setText("Invalid Entry. Please re-enter Username or Password - 1.");
                break;

            case 2: tv.setText("Invalid Entry. Please re-enter Username or Password - 2.");
                break;

            case 3: tv.setText("Invalid Entry. Please re-enter Username or Password - 3.");
                break;

            case 4: 
                    startActivity(intent);

                break;

            default: 

                String sUsername = editUserName.getText().toString();
                String sPassword = editPassword.getText().toString();
                if (sUsername.matches("") & sPassword.matches("")){
                tv.setText("Please enter username or password");
                break;
            }
                break;
            }
```

Comment: What do you get in returnString when edit texts are blank?

Comment: Please sumit more code to get helo. At least the hole method

Comment: @MysticMagic, a JSON object from local host.

Comment: That won't work with Switch case. Check DusteD's answer on your question and convert your JSON object to integer before calling switch case.

Comment: That's not the problem, I already have changed it to an integer, the problem is it doesn't recognise the EditText as empty.

Comment: Then try to get the length edittext.getText().length()

Comment: The one that @Rahul Gupta has mentioned, not working!

Comment: It worked, thank you all for your concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this codeto your button :-

```
if(edittext.getText().length() = 0)
   toast.maketest(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter username and password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
else
  //do your thing
```

Comment: it toasts a message, good, but it still start the other activity

Comment: @Sean which other activity?

Comment: in the else block start your activity

Answer (score 2):

Switch/Case operates on integers in your example, so you should convert your string to an integer:

```
int returnInt = Integer.parseInt(returnString);
switch (returnInt) {
```

Comment: the returnString is an integer, the name is just returnString for my own understanding due to some similarities. 
There's no error in my switch statement

Comment: @Sean are you sureß please use the primitiv int instead of Integer

Comment: I did what you said, but it still doesn't care if the EditTexts are empty, it calls the other activity.
The problem is in my default statement, I guess.